# Can CloudFormation output an array

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template, and its `Outputs` part is like this:

```
"Outputs": {
    "QueueSubscriptions": {
        "Description": "Topics subscribed by queue",
        "Value": {
            "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "BRIDGE2ESBQUEUE", "Subscriptions" ]
        }
    }
}
```

The `Subscriptions` is an array. So, I get the error `Template format error: Every Value member must be a string`. Is there any way to output the `Subscriptions` array in the template? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Fn::Join intrinsic function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html) like this:

```
"Outputs": {
    "QueueSubscriptions": {
        "Description": "Topics subscribed by queue",
        "Value": {
            "Fn::Join" : [ ",", { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "BRIDGE2ESBQUEUE", "Subscriptions" ] } ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah you are right. Please surround your `Fn::GetAtt` function with `{}` and then it will work fine. Thank you!

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Done.